# Detect base64 encoding in PHP?

Tags: php, base64, encode

Is there some way to detect if a string has been base64_encoded() in PHP?

We're converting some storage from plain text to base64 and part of it lives in a cookie that needs to be updated. I'd like to reset their cookie if the text has not yet been encoded, otherwise leave it alone.

Answer (score 26):

Apologies for a late response to an already-answered question, but I don't think base64_decode($x,true) is a good enough solution for this problem. In fact, there may not be a very good solution that works against any given input. For example, I can put lots of bad values into $x and not get a false return value.

```
var_dump(base64_decode('wtf mate',true));
string(5) "���j�"

var_dump(base64_decode('This is definitely not base64 encoded',true));
string(24) "N���^~)��r��[jǺ��ܡם"
```

I think that in addition to the strict return value check, you'd also need to do post-decode validation. The most reliable way is if you could decode and then check against a known set of possible values.

A more general solution with less than 100% accuracy (closer with longer strings, inaccurate for short strings) is if you check your output to see if many are outside of a normal range of utf-8 (or whatever encoding you use) characters.

See this example:

```
<?php
$english = array();
foreach (str_split('az019AZ~~~!@#$%^*()_+|}?><": Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn') as $char) {
  echo ord($char) . "\n";
  $english[] = ord($char);
}
  echo "Max value english = " . max($english) . "\n";

$nonsense = array();
echo "\n\nbase64:\n";
foreach (str_split(base64_decode('Not base64 encoded',true)) as $char) {
  echo ord($char) . "\n";
  $nonsense[] = ord($char);
}

  echo "Max nonsense = " . max($nonsense) . "\n";

?>
```

Results:

```
Max value english = 195
Max nonsense = 233
```

So you may do something like this:

```
if ( $maxDecodedValue > 200 ) {} //decoded string is Garbage - original string not base64 encoded

else {} //decoded string is useful - it was base64 encoded
```

You should probably use the mean() of the decoded values instead of the max(), I just used max() in this example because there is sadly no built-in mean() in PHP. What measure you use (mean,max, etc) against what threshold (eg 200) depends on your estimated usage profile.

In conclusion, the only winning move is not to play. I'd try to avoid having to discern base64 in the first place.

Answer (score 25):

```
function is_base64_encoded($data)
{
    if (preg_match('%^[a-zA-Z0-9/+]*={0,2}$%', $data)) {
       return TRUE;
    } else {
       return FALSE;
    }
};

is_base64_encoded("iash21iawhdj98UH3"); // true
is_base64_encoded("#iu3498r"); // false
is_base64_encoded("asiudfh9w=8uihf"); // false
is_base64_encoded("a398UIhnj43f/1!+sadfh3w84hduihhjw=="); // false
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php#81425

Comment: This is very useful, but your fourth example

`is_base64_encoded("a398UIhnj43f/1!+sadfh3w84hduihhjw=="); // true`

returns FALSE in my tests.

Comment: @Dylan that is because that is not a valid base64. He just commented it wrong.

Comment: This is just matching a string with any length and ending with = or not. It would not tell a difference from a normal string or a base64 encoded one.

Comment: base64_decode returns false if it fails to parse a base64 encoded string, so you'd just need to do: return base64_decode($str) !== false.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem, I ended up with this solution:

```
if ( base64_encode(base64_decode($data)) === $data){
    echo '$data is valid';
} else {
    echo '$data is NOT valid';
}
```

Comment: If I do $data='iujhklsc' I get valid, but it isn't;

Comment: Good testing @Mohit - I can reproduce that problem. It's a clever solution, but apparently doesn't work either. The problem is that base64_decode() will "decode" non-base64 data and then base64_encode() simply reverses the function.

Comment: With `aaaa`, `aaa2` and `abcd` it also comes **true**

Comment: this does not work.  I saw it on another answer as well.. buyer beware.

Comment: does not work for '123412341234'. seriously why do i keep seeing this answer?

Comment: I don't think this answer is worth considering, for the reasons mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: Brilliant! Simple, yet effective!

Comment: any string 4 chars long and above with `[a-Z]` and `[0-9]` will be `valid`!! `base64_encode(base64_decode('test')) === 'test'    // true`

Comment: I don't understand this answer at all. So, you're composing a function with its inverse and you expect to get something different from $data? Obviously this answer fails to detect whether something is in base64 or not.

Comment: fail for real name like - Barthels, Matthies

Answer (score 12):

Better late than never: You could maybe use `mb_detect_encoding()` to find out whether the encoded string appears to have been some kind of text:

```
function is_base64_string($s) {
  // first check if we're dealing with an actual valid base64 encoded string
  if (($b = base64_decode($s, TRUE)) === FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  // now check whether the decoded data could be actual text
  $e = mb_detect_encoding($b);
  if (in_array($e, array('UTF-8', 'ASCII'))) { // YMMV
    return TRUE;
  } else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE** For those who like it short

```
function is_base64_string_s($str, $enc=array('UTF-8', 'ASCII')) {
  return !(($b = base64_decode($str, TRUE)) === FALSE) && in_array(mb_detect_encoding($b), $enc);
}
```

Comment: Simply awesome!! This is probably the best because it allowed the programmer to choose valid list of encoding (of course can be passed as second parameter for added flexibility)

Comment: Really an under-appreciated solution. I blame time difference of answers.

Comment: what if the string encoded are not in either UTF-8 or ASCII...

Comment: @TiamiyuSaheedOluwatosin Then it returns "false".

Comment: @Marki you literally mean base 64 encodings only support the  UTF-8 or ASCII charset

Comment: @TiamiyuSaheedOluwatosin No, that's not what I mean.

Comment: if I input value `555` then this function return `true` while **555** is not valid base 64 encoded.

Comment: @vee If your assertion is true and 555 is indeed not valid then the problem is not this function but rather the fact that `base64_decode()` actually decodes `555` into something while it should not, and probably raise an exception instead. In that case you should start a discussion here: https://www.php.net/manual/function.base64-decode.php (or file a bug)

Comment: Yes, `base64_decode()` do decode something wrong but the OP ask about detect base 64 encoding string while **5555** is not base 64 encoded string. (sorry it is not 555 - I was wrong.) So, this function can't detected that. I found that there are a lot of invalid characters that is `ascii` or `utf-8`. If that case the `mb_detect_encoding()` can't be use for detect decoded base 64 string for 100%.

Comment: @Marki Before or after `mb_detect_encoding()` I suggest you to check with `$b === mb_convert_encoding($b, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8')` again to make very sure that decoded base 64 is valid UTF-8 character. Here is my code to find out how to verify valid unicode character ( https://wtools.io/paste-code/b71K ). Link maybe valid for days.

Answer (score 11):

We can combine three things into one function to check if given string is a valid base 64 encoded or not.

```
function validBase64($string)
{
 $decoded = base64_decode($string, true);
 $result = false;
    
 // Check if there is no invalid character in string
 if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\/\r\n+]*={0,2}$/', $string)) {$result = false;}
        
 // Decode the string in strict mode and send the response
 if (!$decoded) {$result = false;}
        
 // Encode and compare it to original one
 if (base64_encode($decoded) != $string) {$result = false;}
        
 return $result;
}
```

Comment: I think "$str" should actually be "$string" on the second line.

Comment: should you not also check that the length of the input mod 4 == 0?

Comment: @frumbert not all implementations require padding..   but if you were to test mod 4, you would first need to strip all whitespace

Answer (score 5):

I was about to build a base64 toggle in php, this is what I did:

```
function base64Toggle($str) {
    if (!preg_match('~[^0-9a-zA-Z+/=]~', $str)) {
        $check = str_split(base64_decode($str));
        $x = 0;
        foreach ($check as $char) if (ord($char) > 126) $x++;
        if ($x/count($check)*100 < 30) return base64_decode($str);
    }
    return base64_encode($str);
}
```

It works perfectly for me.
Here are my complete thoughts on it: http://www.albertmartin.de/blog/code.php/19/base64-detection

And here you can try it: http://www.albertmartin.de/tools

Comment: I personally love this solution because it gets closest (`return false` in place of `return base64_encode($str)` and `return true` in place of `return base64_decode($str)` and you get a near perfect solution to OP). I appreciate how you explained it on your blog.

Comment: I think you should also check out (Marki's solution)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/51877882/1369473]. It's more flexible and less prone to errors

Answer (score 3):

base64_decode() will not return FALSE if the input is not valid base64 encoded data. Use `imap_base64()` instead, it returns FALSE if $text contains characters outside the Base64 alphabet
[imap_base64() Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-base64.php)

Comment: It is same as `base64_decode($string, true)` i.e., strict form

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution:

`if(empty(htmlspecialchars(base64_decode($string, true)))) {
    return false;
}`

It will return false if the decoded `$string` is invalid, for example: "node", "123", " ", etc.

Comment: Good one. Better than most other

Answer (score 2):

```php
$is_base64 = function(string $string) : bool {
    $zero_one = ['MA==', 'MQ=='];
    if (in_array($string, $zero_one)) return TRUE;

    if (empty(htmlspecialchars(base64_decode($string, TRUE))))
        return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
};

var_dump('*** These yell false ***');
var_dump($is_base64(''));
var_dump($is_base64('This is definitely not base64 encoded'));
var_dump($is_base64('node'));
var_dump($is_base64('node '));
var_dump($is_base64('123'));
var_dump($is_base64(0));
var_dump($is_base64(1));
var_dump($is_base64(123));
var_dump($is_base64(1.23));

var_dump('*** These yell true ***');
var_dump($is_base64(base64_encode('This is definitely base64 encoded')));
var_dump($is_base64(base64_encode('node')));
var_dump($is_base64(base64_encode('123')));
var_dump($is_base64(base64_encode(0)));
var_dump($is_base64(base64_encode(1)));
var_dump($is_base64(base64_encode(123)));
var_dump($is_base64(base64_encode(1.23)));
var_dump($is_base64(base64_encode(TRUE)));

var_dump('*** Should these yell true? Might be edge cases ***');
var_dump($is_base64(base64_encode('')));
var_dump($is_base64(base64_encode(FALSE)));
var_dump($is_base64(base64_encode(NULL)));
```

Answer (score 1):

May be it's not exactly what you've asked for. But hope it'll be usefull for somebody.

In my case the solution was to encode all data with json_encode and then base64_encode.

```
$encoded=base64_encode(json_encode($data));
```

this value could be stored or used whatever you need.
Then to check if this value isn't just a text string but your data encoded you simply use

```
function isData($test_string){
   if(base64_decode($test_string,true)&&json_decode(base64_decode($test_string))){
      return true;
   }else{
    return false;
   }
```

or alternatively

```
function isNotData($test_string){
   if(base64_decode($test_string,true)&&json_decode(base64_decode($test_string))){
      return false;
   }else{
    return true;
   }
```

Thanks to all previous answers authors in this thread:)

Comment: If not `json_encode()` first... here is the problem.
**aGVsbG8=** is base64 encoded string of **hello**. `isData('aGVsbG8=')` should be `true` but got `false`. 
`json_decode()` can't detect for correctly decoded base 64 string.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a text in base64 has no spaces.

I used this function which worked fine for me. It tests if the number of spaces in the string is less than 1 in 20.

e.g: at least 1 space for each 20 chars --- ( spaces / strlen ) < 0.05

```
function normalizaBase64($data){
    $spaces = substr_count ( $data ," ");
    if (($spaces/strlen($data))<0.05)
    {
        return base64_decode($data);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is:

```
$base64_test = mb_substr(trim($some_base64_data), 0, 76);
return (base64_decode($base64_test, true) === FALSE ? FALSE : TRUE);
```