# How do I get codeIgniter 2, Bradley - SignaturePad and DomPDF to work correctly

Tags: json, codeigniter, dompdf

Hello: I am using signaturePad [`http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/`]and have created a short web form in codeIgniter 2, located here: [`http://gentest.lfwebz.com/crd/open_form3`], that requires the users to actually sign the form.
I have also installed mPDF and domPDF and I have them working, sort of, but not quite the way I want it to.

The functionality I want is this: User opens web form, fills it out, signs it,
using signPad mentioned above.  I then want to click a button that runs mPDF/domPDF and 
captures the page and of course the **embedded signature**.

When I run mpdf/domPDF and pass it the view that houses the form, I think I have figured out it is just grabbing a fresh view, one without the signature, but several parts
of the form are missing. So after digging around, I think I have determined that I have to use image conversion of the signaturePad - this is where I am stuck.  I have the code in, using the reference here: [Signature pad and dompdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404136/signature-pad-and-dompdf/17422596#17422596), but it does not work.

If you go to my page here: `http://gentest.lfwebz.com/crd/open_form3`, sign the page, click the "I accept" button

**Here is my view**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/jquery.signaturepad.css" media="screen">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.signaturepad.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo base_url(); ?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>pdf.php" class="sigPad">
  <label for="name">Print your name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="name">
  <p class="typeItDesc">Review your signature</p>
  <p class="drawItDesc">Draw your signature</p>
  <ul class="sigNav">
    <li class="typeIt"><a href="#type-it" class="current">Type It</a></li>
    <li class="drawIt"><a href="#draw-it">Draw It</a></li>
    <li class="clearButton"><a href="#clear">Clear</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="sig sigWrapper">
    <div class="typed"></div>
    <canvas class="pad" width="198" height="55"></canvas>
    <input type="text" name="output" class="output">
    <input type="text" name="imgOutput" class="imgOutput">
  </div>
  <br /><br /><br />
  <button type="submit">I accept the terms of this agreement.</button>
</form>
<script>
  var sig;
  $( document ).ready( function ( ) {
    sig = $('.sigPad').signaturePad({defaultAction:'drawIt'});
  } );
  $( '.sigPad' ).submit( function ( evt ) {
    $( '.imgOutput' ).val( sig.getSignatureImage( ) );
  } );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**here is the controller or the pdf.php mentioned above:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['imgOutput'])){$img_output = $_POST['imgOutput'];}

echo "position 1";
$bse = preg_replace('#^data:image/[^;]+;base64,#', '', $img_output );
echo "position 2";
echo $bse;
if ( base64_encode( base64_decode( $bse) ) === $bse ) {

  require_once 'dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';
  $html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><p>Your signature:</p><br /><img src="'. $img_output .'"></body></html>';
  $dompdf = new DOMPDF;
  $dompdf->load_html( $html );
  $dompdf->render( );
  $dompdf->stream("test.pdf");
} 
        else{
                echo ("ERROR !");
            }
?>
```

What am I missing here?  Please could some one point me in the right direction?

Let me know if you need more info.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to output the pdf without echoing before

Comment: The code seems to be doing what you tell it to do. You can't stream a PDF if you've already sent content to the web browser. But you may not be getting any notices about this if ZF is suppressing errors. As mentioned by @lighta try removing your echo statements. Also, it would help to know what you expect to happen, what is actually happening, and any errors you receive.

Comment: HI - i put the echo in just confirm that the function/method was being reached.  If i remove them, nothing happens, though when I echo $bse, I see the data.  What I want is a pdf of my page with the signature.  If you go to my test here: `http://gentest.lfwebz.com/crd/open_form3`, after your sign, I would like to have a pdf of the page including the signature.

Comment: Maybe Dompdf cannot resolves base64 image, so try with an url and still not echoing before.

Comment: Nothing happenns? You mean you get a blank page? Even if dompdf can't resolve the image it should produce a PDF. ZF is probably suppressing errors. Doesn't ZF include a "developer" mode that will display errors? You could also wrap that block in some try/catch logic to try and figure out what's going on.