# How to display image from data base to php

Tags: php, html, mysql

[here2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aACHt.png)

```
<body>
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','warframe');
  $load = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM frames");
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($load)) {
    echo "<div class='content'>
    <div class='frame'>**<img src='data:image;base64,".$rows['image']."'>**
        <div class='frame__name'>
                <p>$row[frame_name]</p>
            </div>
    </div>";
        }

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
    
</body>
```

`My DataBase:
id_frame int(11) primary key AI
frame_name varchar(30)
image longblob

images are displayed encoded, which makes me a bit nervous. I've seen about 10 tutorial, posts but it's still not working. Need help. Name display (frame_name) works fine`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve images from MySQL database and display in an html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793009/how-to-retrieve-images-from-mysql-database-and-display-in-an-html-tag)

Comment: It looks almost perfect, but the images are displayed as these little curved paper icons, so it doesn't work @hassan

Comment: Is base64 string  correctly inserted in your table? check https://stackoverflow.com/a/10797086/6934036 or use https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Answer (score 0):

assuming your base64 is valid this:

```
<body>
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','warframe');
  $load = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM frames");
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($load)) {
    echo "<div class='content'>
    <div class='frame'>**<img src=\"data:image;base64,".$row['image']."\">**
        <div class='frame__name'>
            <p>".$row["frame_name"]."</p>
        </div>
    </div>";
        }

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
    
</body>
```

if didn't work share your output html.

Comment: It's all what i have in this php file, name display work fine but with images is harder like, it display me encoded images that's it

Comment: i see. share the html output from browser by pressing Ctrl+u

Comment: how/where can i share it? it's 1300 too long, `code` doesn't work

Comment: i've changed post, click "here" to check the code.
P.S on the right is older code version

Comment: there is a typo. change $rows['image'] to $row['image'] and test again

Comment: Errors has been fixed, but images are still encoded, might it be something with base64? here2 - screen

Comment: yes the image you stored in database is not base64. you have to make another php (image.php) and get images by id (image.php?id=123) then only echo that string with a relevant header to your image format. then use the address of that file in your img tag src