# RegEx Fails on Known Good Value

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex designed to detect plausible Base64 strings.  It works in tests at https://regex101.com for all expected test values.

```
~^((?:[a-zA-Z0-9/+]{4})*(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9/+]{3}=)|(?:[a-zA-Z0-9/+]{2}==))?)$~
```

However, when I use this pattern in PHP, I find some values inexplicably fail.

```
$tests = array(
    'MFpGQkVBJTNkJTNkfTxCUj4NCg0KICAgIDwvZm9udD4=',
    'MFpGRkVBJTNkJTNkfTxCUj4NCg0KICAgIDwvZm9udD4=',
    'MFpGSkVBJTNkJTNkfTxCUj4NCg0KICAgIDwvZm9udD4=',
);

foreach ($tests as $str) {
    $result = preg_match(
        '~^((?:[a-zA-Z0-9/+]{4})*(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9/+]{3}=)|(?:[a-zA-Z0-9/+]{2}==))?)$~i',
        preg_replace('~[\s\R]~u', "", $str)
    );

    var_dump($result);
}
```

results:

```
int(1)
int(0)
int(1)
```

Question:  Why does this pattern fail for the second test string?

Comment: Maybe you don't need RegEx for this :) there is a good answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556345/detect-base64-encoding-in-php (second answer)

Comment: what's the purpose of that `preg_replace`?

Comment: `preg_replace` to eliminate the whitespace (newlines) so common in blocks of base64.

Comment: @Marc, I'm actually going to do a sanity check after conditionally decoding, similar to that, but I want to pre-test also.  It's critical we don't get a false positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is in your `preg_replace` call:

```
preg_replace('~[\s\R]~u', "", $str)
```

Inside character class `\R` is matching and removing literal `R` from 2nd element in array and thus causing `preg_match` to fail.

Change it to:

```
preg_replace('~\s|\R~u', "", $str)
```

As `\s` will also match `\R` you can just do:

```
preg_replace('~\s+~u', "", $str)
```

Comment: Yes, that's it.  I wasn't aware that `\R` would break down in a character class.  Do you know why that is, or, which shorthands work and don't work in character classes?

Comment: [See here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Backslash-sequences) It says: **`\R` matches anything that can be considered a newline under Unicode rules. It's not a character class, as it can match a multi-character sequence. Therefore, it cannot be used inside a bracketed character class**